# Vite HMR not reloading once rename the filename of functional component

Tags: reactjs, vite, bundler

I created functional component file name starting with small letter wrongly, for example **profile.jsx** and then I saved the project.

After I realized, I change the first letter to capital like **Profile.jsx**, then it never been reloaded by hmr forever. every time I should `ctrl x` and then run again `npm run dev`

I tried to delete build file, and rerun the project, still same
I deleted the **Profile.jsx** and re created the same name, then still same, hmr not reloading

I have faced similar problem before also with different filename, Now I cannot use this filename ever

> **Note:** the other components is reloading properly